# How can I replace a word that is in html content (not attributes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I want to replace a word that is in html content (not attributes) and I've googled and found variant regular expressions, but none of them could not cover all cases.

for example replace "width" to "[width]"

```
<div style="width: 200px">
    width is 300.
    <div>
        <div style="width: 100px">
            width is 200.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div style="width: 200px">
    [width] is 300.
    <div>
        <div style="width: 100px">
            [width] is 200.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Example [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/mhdhadjar/VNKen/)

Comment: @FelixKling nice one, I've adopted this site :D

Comment: @FelixKling TL;DR but far too much truth... :)

Comment: Unless you want to wake the great lord of destruction Cthulhu, you should not parse HTML with regex... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: for example this is wrong (attribute replaced)! $(".result").html($(".main").html().replace(/\bwidth\b/g,'[width]'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said in my comment, iterate over all text nodes and replace their content.

```
function replaceText(element, pattern, replacement) {

    for(var child = element.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if(child.nodeType === 3) {
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(pattern, replacement);
        }
        else if(child.nodeType === 1) {
            replaceText(child, pattern, replacement);
        }
    }

}
```

Assuming `element` is a reference to the root:

```
replaceText(element, /(\b)width(\b)/g, '$1[width]$2');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sCgGZ/)

If you haven't parsed the HTML yet, you can create a temporary element:

```
var tmp_root = document.createElement('div');
tmp_root.innerHTML = yourHTMLString;
```

Something similar can be done with jQuery using [`.contents()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all child nodes, including text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace(/\b(width)\b/g, '[$1]');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zp8qE/

You have to use `.html` instead of `.text` (and `\b` to check for word boundaries) because you have divs nested inside of other divs.

Change `/g` to `/gi` for case-insensitive searching.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of not replacing the text inside the html params.

Comment: @cambraca Really? I'm not having a problem with it.

Comment: If you inspect element, you will see that within the style attribute, width is replaced with [width]. try instead using .contents, filter to only text nodes, then replace within those text nodes. Here is a plugin that does that to accomplish a different goal: https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-highlightText

Comment: Please see the example I have add in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("*").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/(\b)width(\b)/g, '$1[width]$2');
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/4LpdK/5/).

The idea is to iterate through all the "text" elements of the document. I took jQuery's [example code from its docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and modified it a bit.

You can, of course, change the first selector to make this work only on the elements you want (for example you could have `$("div")` there instead of `$("*")`).

Comment: By the way `nodeType == 1` means the element is a text element and not, say, a `div` or whatever.

Comment: Please see the example [http://jsfiddle.net/mhdhadjar/VNKen/](http://jsfiddle.net/mhdhadjar/VNKen/)